# Multiple passwords for simple password protected page

Tags: php, html, forms, passwords, password-protection

I have a super simple page that uses a PHP password script to allow users access. It works like a charm, but I need to add a second password for another user. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thank you!

/A

PHP:

```
<?php 

// Define your password 
$password = "xxx"; 

if ($_POST['txtPassword'] != $password) { 

?>
```

HTML:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> 
    <p>Enter Password</p><br>
<input type="password" name="txtPassword" style="width: 400px;">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$passwords = array('xxx', 'zzz', 'yyy');

if (!in_array($_POST['txtPassword'], $passwords, true)) {

}
```

Comment: No need for 2 answers the same. Guess we think alike

Comment: Selected answer would be nice, maybe even an upvote ;)?

Comment: Come to think of it, you might not have upvote yet; thanks for the selected answer anyway ;)